# Execute PL/SQL procedure from vb6 on Oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, vb6

I am trying to call a PL/SQL procedure which has an output value from a Visual Basic 6 function, but it does not work.
Here my code.

PL/SQL code (so far, it is just a mock):

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE IS_SINISTRO_ABS_MOCK 
(   numPol      in VARCHAR2,
    codGaranzia in VARCHAR2,
    res out BOOLEAN
    ) AS 
BEGIN
  res := TRUE;
END IS_SINISTRO_ABS_MOCK;
```

VB6 code:

```
Private Function IsSinistroInABS(NumPol As String, CodGaranzia As String) As Boolean
Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection

With dbConn
    .Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
    .Properties("Data Source") = "*********"
    .Properties("User Id") = "ROUTING"
    .Properties("Password") = "***********"
    .Open
End With


Dim dbCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim result As Boolean
Set dbCmd = New ADODB.Command
dbCmd.ActiveConnection = dbConn
dbCmd.CommandTimeout = 300
dbCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
dbCmd.CommandText = "{CALL ROUTING.IS_SINISTRO_ABS_MOCK(?,?,?)}"

dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter(, adLongVarChar, adParamInput, _ 
Len(NumPol), NumPol)
dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter(, adLongVarChar, adParamInput, _ 
Len(CodGaranzia), CodGaranzia)
dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter(, adBoolean, adParamOutput, , _ 
result)
dbCmd.Prepared = True

dbCmd.Execute

IsSinistroInABS = dbCmd.Parameters("res").value

dbConn.Close

End Function
```

The DB connection works properly, indeed I succeeded in executing a standard SQL query, but I get an unspecified error when I try to run the procedure. I succeeded also in launching a procedure without any parameters. As a result, the problem is supposed to be in the use of them.

Note that the procedure is a standalone one. In other words, it is not included in any package.

Comment: maybe you will find this link on so helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264234/using-oracle-stored-procedure-in-vb-through-adodb-connection

Comment: At which line does the error occur when you step through `IsSinistroInABS`?

Comment: I don't know. The error message just warns me that an unspecified error occurred.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor
Thanks but my problem is 99% caused by using parameters, since I succeed in launching a procedure without any of them.

Comment: @danieledc: if you take a close look to the other question, he uses named parameters.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I tried to use named parameters but nothing changed.

Comment: Try this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10118/o4o00859.htm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late (you posted your question 2.5 years ago), but I got the same problem.
After a lot of digging and frustration, I found out the error occurs when the stored procedure has **numeric output parameters** (VARCHAR is OK as well as any input parameter).

I finally found out that everything works correctly when you use the ancient DB-provider **`MSDAORA.1`**.